# Publishing Service, transactions are atomic?

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

I want to publish content to 2 targets (Web1 & Web 2), assume if i have 2 items to publish and using Publishing Service 2.0

- Item A
- Item B

If am using Sitecore Publishing service, what will happen in the following scenario ?

1. Will the Item A & Item B will be published to Web1, then Item A & Item B will be published to Web 2, what is the sequence item will published ?
2. Will the Item A will be published to Web1 & Web 2, then Item B will be published to Web 1 & Web 2 ?
3. What will happen when Item A & Item B will be published to Web1, failed to published to Web 2, will the whole publish transaction roll back ? do we have any configuration setting we can make this happen, so that it will either publish to both web 1 & Web 2 or it will not publish to any Web 1 / Web 2 ?

Appreciate you inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite a lot of questions all at once but I'll try and answer as best I can.

I'm not sure if your using version 1 or 2 of the publishing service but you should find that since these are two targets then two manifests are created (one for web1 and one for web2).

However for performance the new publishing service will execute publishing in batches and also will do things in parallel, e.g it might be checking one batch of items for workflow or restrictions and at the same time it will also be getting the next batch from the database.

This suggests that it's unlikely to complete the promotion of all content for Web 1 before proceeding with promoting content to Web 2.

Also the standard publishing pipelines do not fire so you can't use any of these.

You can however use the new `publishEndResultBatch` pipeline to get a list of items updated in that batch and using this you could perhaps look to apply custom logic to roll-back the publish of item A & B to Web 1 if they subsequently fail to publish to Web 2.

It should also be noted that the Publishing Service does raise the same publish events as the old publishing system, e.g the `publish:end:remote` event. So perhaps you could use these to implement some business logic also.

Hopefully this helps.